# Spring Boot - Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.stream.Stream

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, stream

I need to stream a Object List, but when i try it using JpaRepository and @Query, i receive this exception:

`Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'MainApplication': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'service'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'MyServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'myDAO'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'MyDAO': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.stream.Stream com.my.package.dao.MyDAO.streamAll()!`

MyDAO code:

```
@Repository
public interface MyDAO extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Long> {

    @QueryHints(value = @QueryHint(name = HINT_FETCH_SIZE, value = "" + 
        Integer.MIN_VALUE))
    @Query(value = "SELECT m FROM MyEntity m")
    Stream<MyEntity> streamAll();

    ...
}
```

Main code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.my.package.*")
@EntityScan("com.my.package.*")
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class MainApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    MyServiceInterface service;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MainApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

        try {
            service.createCsv();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }

}
```

I have tried everything but nothing works, please help me!

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please add the full stack trace and not just a snippet. Tip place your `MainApplication` in `com.my.package` and remove all annotations but `@SpringBootApplication`. By not doing it you loose some of the auto config/detect features of Spring Boot. Also a negative fetch size looks a bit strange.

Comment: Please don't add code/stacktraces as comments... Edit your question instead.

Comment: I've added other annotations for trying by some tutorials, but however also without them, error is the same, however, now i've added full stacktrace!

Comment: There must be more in the stacktrace as the validation should also tell you why it is failing.

Comment: so you are getting Unsatisfied dependency error so you didn't map spring dependency proper way. Autowired, Service and Repository.

Comment: no, because before when I used criteriabuilder it worked ,  instead now with @Query and JpaRepository don't work.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to use `Stream<MyEntity> findAll();` because `JpaRepository` already defined the method with a `List` return type, so you can rename your method like that `Stream<MyEntity> getAll();` or use Ordering to rename the method like `Stream<MyEntity> findAllByOrderByIdAsc();`.

Answer (score -1):

Just remove

```
@Query(value = "SELECT m FROM MyEntity m")
```

and use findAll() method of JPARepository like below

```
Stream<MyEntity> findAll();
```

Comment: findAll() method of JPARepository return a List, but i need a Stream type, and however, if i need a more specific query can't use findAll()